# The first row is not printing properly when generating PDF

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf

I have following html code in my document for generating PDF, but resulted PDF is not generating properly.

```
<table border="1"  class="table table-striped">

    <thead>
        <th>Sr No.</th>
        <th>Particulars </th>
        <th>Qty </th>
        <th>rate </th>
        <th>Amount </th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <br><br>
        @foreach($data as $row)

        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row['temp_invoice_id']  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row['tyre_brand']." ".$row['tyre_model']  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row['quantity']  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row['rate']  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row['total']  }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But when the PDF is generated it shows something like this I don't know why it's not generating proper PDF can anyone have solution over this problem, or we have to apply separate `css` for print media?

[image]

Comment: How are you generating the PDF? Does it look correct in the browser? You could lose the `<br><br>` inside `<tbody>` I guess.

Comment: Which plugin you're using for PDF generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside thead use tr tag it is working fine.

```
     <thead>
        <th>Sr No.</th>
        <th>Particulars </th>
        <th>Qty </th>
        <th>rate </th>
        <th>Amount </th>
    </thead>
```

use like this,

```
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Sr No.</th>
            <th>Particulars </th>
            <th>Qty </th>
            <th>rate </th>
            <th>Amount </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br><br>` snippet in your `<tbody>` they are not valid, so the browser might ignore them but maybe the PDF generator (I don't know which one you use) might not.
Also place the `<th>`s inside a row (`<tr>`)